# Grails/Eclipse: Native Library jline_.dll already loaded in another classloader

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am seeing the following error when trying to run various grails tasks (like generate-controller) from the String STS IDE (Eclipse).  It seems like this start after I installed EGit, but I'm not sure about that.

Anyone seen things like this before?

Error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace".
Native Library C:\Users\mtyson\AppData\Local\Temp\jline_.dll already loaded in another classloader
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a STS Spring issue.

I run grails 'clean' from the IDE while run-app is going on, and it somehow loses track of the run-app process.  The console doesn't think the app is running, but it is running in the background (ctrl-alt-del reveals it in task man).  After that, the mentioned .dll error appears.  Solution is to just kill the rogue process.

Comment: I have been encountering this error continually. It just won't go away. I downloaded Process Explorer, and see no run-app process to kill. It just keeps popping up on just about every single action.  I've tried wiping and re-installing STS 2.9.2.  I did NOT have this problem prior to the 2.1.0 Grails upgrade.  Another user who posted on nabble made this same observation.

Comment: When that process is there, it just appears as a generic java process.  The only way I could I identify it from the eclipse process is it was using less memory.  Good luck.

Comment: I ended up deleting the ivy cache and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

[Upgrade your sts/ggts version](http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts) to 3.2.0.M1 or higher. The bug is fixed

Answer (score 0):

It seems the bug of STS, [try this solution](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?132974-Native-Library-jline_-dll-already-loaded-in-another-classloader)

Answer (score 0):

If you have old setup and not want upgrade then delete dll from temp location and restart eclipse. It works for me.